# How do I reliably release memory in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, memory

If I have this code

```
 NSString *postData = [@"foo=" stringByAppendingString:fooText.text];
 ...
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
 ...
 [postData release];   //this causes crash
 [request release];    //this causes crash
```

Now I understand this is the [expected behavior according to Apple's documents](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB). Now if i remove the release code the crash doesn't happen but I find that the memory leaks anyway for *request. So I rewrite the code

```
NSString *postData;
//postData = [NSString alloc];  // this line commented out since OP
postData = [@"foo=" stringByAppendingString:fooText.text];
...
NSMutableURLRequest *request;
request = [NSMutableURLRequest alloc];
request = [request initWithURL:url];
    ...
    [postData release];   //this still crashes #
    [request release];    //this works fine
```

I don't really understand why it would crash at # . Is there any recommended best practice here? I think I must be missing something because I often see the 'shorthand' approach (top) having a release (Kochan, Programming in Objective-C for example), but the Apple docs say that it's wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general rule of thumb, if you are calling a helper static method (such as `stringByAppendingString`), then you shouldn't release it. That string was added to an autorelease pool before being given to you. If you are calling `alloc` then an `init...` method, then you are responsible for releasing that object.

Other things to note in your code:

- In the second example, you alloc postData, then immediately replace it with another string created by `stringByAppendingString`, that is a memory leak.
- Your release calls are wrong, they should be `[postData release]` and `[request release]`
- I don't see any correlation between `postData` and `request` in your example, so not sure exactly what you are getting at with the two of them.

Comment: "The general rule of thumb, if you are calling a helper static method (such as stringByAppendingString), then you shouldn't release it." That was what I was looking for! However, how would I release the *request in the first example given that instruments was indicating that there was a memory leak (this is all inside a simple method). This would seem to indicate the autorelease wasn't working for *request.

Comment: In the first example, you allocated and initted request yourself, so you should release it. What is the crash you get when you do? EXC_BAD_ACCESS? That usually means you've (or something you gave request to) already released request and you didn't realize it.

Answer (score 1):

First, in your second example, the line `postData = [NSString alloc];` is completely unnecessary - `postData` is overwritten by the next line. Second, to answer your question as to why things crash - there is no good answer - the system can choose to free up memory anytime after the retain count hits 0. To more easily debug the issue, you should turn on [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), which will immediately scribble any objects which are deallocated, giving you a 100% reliable way to test crashes.

Also, it is bad style to alloc/init on separate lines.

In general, you should focus on following the memory guidelines. If you're not following the guidelines, behavior can be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Allocating memory for your object and initializing it better perform in single line - init method may return different object and also it may help to avoid mistake you've made in 2nd example:

```
NSString *postData; // Define pointer to string
postData = [NSString alloc]; // Allocating nsstring pointer and assign it to variable
postData = [@"foo=" stringByAppendingString:fooText.text]; // assign to postData new **autoreleased** string object. result of the previous assignment is abandoned.
[postData release];  //so here you release autoreleased object!!
```

I cannot figure out why  [equest release]; causes crash in the 1st example though.

P.S. I'm not completely wake up or it should be `[postData release]` instead of `[release postData]` ?

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *postData;
postData = [[NSString alloc]init];
postData = [@"foo=" stringByAppendingString:fooText.text];
...
NSMutableURLRequest *request;
request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
...
    [postData release];   
    [request release];
```

Try this.

Comment: Your example still have same problems with postdata as in original question

Comment: its better to add [postData release]; as soon as you finished using that variable. You have to release memory after its use.

Comment: postData contains autoreleased object after assignment in 3rd line - you must not release it. and you allocated string in 2nd line just leaks as you simply overwrite it.

Comment: NSString *postData = [[NSString alloc]init];
postData = @"foo=%@",[fooText.text];
this also might be used, note that this may not be the reason for your problem.